# disable onClick event for particular Element

Tags: jquery, html

i have overlapping image and div . Div is on top , i have written flip() for div which takes some time to complete, if user click on image while it is fliping then instead of flip image click is called .. can i disables on click function for that particular image

Image Click and Div  :

```
 $('#front').live('click', function()  {


 $('#myImageFlow img').live('click', function() {
```

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: What's the HTML look like?

Comment: Can you post your Code here?

Comment: yeah post some more code..

Comment: You might be interested in the 'one' event handler attachment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: more code?
the image's event is inside front event?

Comment: @ PiLHA independent even ... image and div are inside #myimageflow

Comment: @DJDavid98 it depends on what version of jQuery is being used, which isn't stated.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe save the transition state as data on the image. Once the transition is complete, set the data to some flag. You can then check this flag before starting a flip and if necessary, you can stop an event by either returning false from the event handler or by calling `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

```
$('#myImageFlow img').on('click', function (event){ 
  var $img = $(this);
  if !($img.data('isTransitionFinished') {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  } else {
    $img.flip(); // Assuming you made flip a jQuery plugin
  }
};

$.fn.flip = function() {
  this.data('isTransitionFinished', false);  // Reset from any previous transitions
  var properties = {};  // Whatever property changes you're applying for the transition
  this.animate(properties, {
    complete: function() {
      this.data('isTransitionFinished', true);
    }
  });
}
```